# How to add cc & bcc in Messaging.SingleEmailMessage Email and simultaneously avoid single Email limit being hit

Tags: apex, governorlimits, singleemailmessage, massemailmessage, emailmessage

My requirement is to send single email with To/Cc/Bcc added. All the email Ids belong to internal users.

Initially, when I was passing the User.Id to these methods, I was hitting the Single Email Limit Exceeded error.

```
email.setToAddress(user1.Id);
email.setBccAddress(user2.Id); 
email.setCcAddress(user3.Id);
```

To get around this limit, I figured out that when User's Id is passed to setTargetObjectId method then the email sent is not counted against daily limit of 5000 emails.

```
email.setTargetObjectId(User.Id) // to be used instead of setToAddress()
```

Now, after sorting the problem for setToAddress, I am unsure around how to still include anything equivalent to cc & bcc emails of internal users.

Appreciate any suggestions/recommendations ?

Comment: Hi @Lord, did you find a solution to this challenge?